# Hilt Failed To Build

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to migrate from Dagger to Hilt but I got this build error

BaseApplication, expected to be annotated with @DefineComponent. Found: @kotlin.Metadata(mv={1, 4, 1}, bv={1, 0, 3}, k=1, d1={"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\b\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0016\u00a8\u0006\u0005"}, d2={"Lcom/example/unioncoop/BaseApplication;", "Landroid/app/Application;", "()V", "onCreate", "", "app_debug"}),@dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

I don't know where the error and this is my code
My Application Class

```
@HiltAndroidApp       
class BaseApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
  }
}
```

Activity Class

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity () {}
```

My Module

```
@Module   
@InstallIn(BaseApplication.class)  
public class NetworkModule {
private static final String BASE_URL = "";

@Provides
OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.w("Logger", "log: " + message));
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
}

@Provides
public Gson getGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new NullStringToEmptyAdapterFactory())
            .serializeNulls()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
}

@Provides
Retrofit getRetrofit(OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced BaseApplication with ApplicationComponent in `InstallIn` annotation like the below and every thing worked fine.

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
```